# Proving first order logic in coq

Tags: propositional-calculus, theorem-provers

I want to prove something like:

Theorem new_theorem : $\forall (A B: \text{Prop}), ((A \wedge B) \iff (B \wedge A))$.

in coq. I know, i could just type *firstorder.*, but could i prove this in coq without this tactic and if so how?

Comment: https://coq.inria.fr/tutorial/1-basic-predicate-calculus gives details under 1.3.1

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'll post a sequence of proof scripts, starting from an "uphill both ways, in the snow" version that elaborately proofs every single step.

Version 1:

```
Require Import Utf8.

Lemma and_commutative: ∀ P Q, P ∧ Q ↔ Q ∧ P.
Proof.
  intros P Q.
  split.
  - intros HPandQ.
    destruct HPandQ as [HP HQ].
    split.
    + exact HQ.
    + exact HP.
  - intros HQandP.
    destruct HQandP as [HQ HP].
    split.
    + exact HP.
    + exact HQ.
Qed.
```

This splits the proof into two goals, $P \wedge Q \to Q \wedge P$ and  $Q \wedge P \to  P \wedge Q$. It proves each by splitting the assumtion in its constituent parts, splitting the goal into two subgoals and solving the subgoals with the corresponding assumptions.

Looking at this proof, there's a lot of duplication: we can simplify it with a lemma, like this:

```
Require Import Utf8.

Lemma and_commutative: ∀ P Q, P ∧ Q ↔ Q ∧ P.
Proof.
  assert (∀ P Q, P ∧ Q → Q ∧ P) as Himplication. {
    intros P Q HPandQ.
    destruct HPandQ as [HP HQ].
    split.
    + exact HQ.
    + exact HP.
  }
  intros P Q.
  split.
  - apply Himplication.
  - apply Himplication.
Qed.
```

This is basically the same proof as before, only made more succinct by using an `assert`.

There's yet another improvement to be made: we are laboriously using `exact` to prove the goals, but they follow trivially from assumptions. Let's simplify again:

```
Require Import Utf8.

Lemma and_commutative: ∀ P Q, P ∧ Q ↔ Q ∧ P.
Proof.
  assert (∀ P Q, P ∧ Q → Q ∧ P) as Himplication. {
    intros P Q HPandQ.
    destruct HPandQ as [HP HQ].
    split; assumption.
  }
  intros P Q.
  split; apply Himplication.
Qed.
```

This uses a `;` tactical to shorten the proof a bit more, by merging identical tactic sequences into one. A final simplification would be to use introduction patterns and the fact that `split` will auto-introduce assumptions if neccessary:

```
Require Import Utf8.

Lemma and_commutative: ∀ P Q, P ∧ Q ↔ Q ∧ P.
Proof.
  assert (∀ P Q, P ∧ Q → Q ∧ P) as Himplication. {
    intros P Q  [HP HQ].
    split; assumption.
  }
  split; apply Himplication.
Qed.
```

Further improvement would be possible here by using `auto` instead of the `split; ...` sequences, but at this point, we're almost at the level of using `firstorder` anyway...

JFTR: I only `Require Import Utf8` so that I can use unicode symbols such as \forall and \leftrightarrow; it has no influence on the proofs themselves.